# Why can't PostgreSQL do this simple FULL JOIN?

Tags: postgresql, join

Here's a minimal setup with 2 tables `a` and `b` each with 3 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX ON a (value);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX ON b (value);

INSERT INTO a (value) VALUES ('x'), ('y'),        (NULL);
INSERT INTO b (value) VALUES        ('y'), ('z'), (NULL);
```

Here is a LEFT JOIN that works fine as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value;
```

with output:

```
 id | value | id | value 
----+-------+----+-------
  1 | x     |    | 
  2 | y     |  1 | y
  3 |       |  3 | 
(3 rows)
```

Changing "LEFT JOIN" to "FULL JOIN" gives an error:

```
SELECT * FROM a
FULL JOIN b ON a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value;
```

ERROR:  FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions

Can someone please answer:

What is a "merge-joinable or hash-joinable join condition" and why joining on `a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value` doesn't fulfill this condition, but `a.value = b.value` is perfectly fine?

It seems that the only difference is how NULL values are handled. Since the `value` column is indexed in both tables, running an `EXPLAIN` on a `NULL` lookup is just as efficient as looking up values that are non-`NULL`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE value = 'x';
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on a  (cost=4.20..13.67 rows=6 width=36)
   Recheck Cond: (value = 'x'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on a_value_idx  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0)
         Index Cond: (value = 'x'::text)


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE value ISNULL;
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on a  (cost=4.20..13.65 rows=6 width=36)
   Recheck Cond: (value IS NULL)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on a_value_idx  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0)
         Index Cond: (value IS NULL)
```

This has been tested with PostgreSQL 9.6.3 and 10beta1.

There has been [discussion about this issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060313104028.GB6714@svana.org), but it doesn't directly answer the above question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the linked mail thread answers your question perfectly. Especially [this one](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9075.1142275758%40sss.pgh.pa.us) "*What is the definition of a merge-joinable condition? - Equality on a sortable datatype*". However the equality cannot be determined if you take NULL  values into account which `is not distinct from` has to do (`NULL = NULL` doesn't return a value - it returns "unknown")

Comment: I can only add that `FULL JOIN` in postgres is only implemented for operators that supports merge-joins and hash-joins. You can obtain the list of operators by `select oprname from  pg_operator where oprcanmerge or oprcanhash;`. On my localhost DB it is unsurprisingly only '=' operator. I repeat, it is an implementation feature. Also, you can replace the query with two combined queries - left and right join, as shown in above-mentioned mail-thread. For merge- and hash-join, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Join_algorithms .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL implements `FULL OUTER JOIN` with either a hash or a merge join.

To be eligible for such a join, the join condition has to have the form

```
<expression using only left table> <operator> <expression using only right table>
```

Now your join condition *does* look like this, but PostgreSQL does not have a special `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator, so it parses your condition into:

```
(NOT ($1 IS DISTINCT FROM $2))
```

And such an expression cannot be used for hash or merge joins, hence the error message.

I can think of a way to work around it:

```
SELECT a_id, NULLIF(a_value, '<null>'),
       b_id, NULLIF(b_value, '<null>')
FROM (SELECT id AS a_id,
             COALESCE(value, '<null>') AS a_value
      FROM a
     ) x
   FULL JOIN
     (SELECT id AS b_id,
             COALESCE(value, '<null>') AS b_value
      FROM b
     ) y
      ON x.a_value = y.b_value;
```

That works if `<null>` does not appear anywhere in the `value` columns.

Comment: Indeed, running `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value` does in fact show that the join clause is being parsed as `(NOT (a.value IS DISTINCT FROM b.value))` and is quite expensive, which is a shame, because it seems that it could efficiently be an equality-with-NULL join operation. Thanks; that's what I was looking for.
Btw another work-around is
`SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM a
RIGHT JOIN b ON a.value IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.value
WHERE a.id ISNULL` and requires column `a.id` is not null.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved such a case by replacing the ON condition with "TRUE", and moving the original "ON" condition into a WHERE clause. I don't know the performance impact of this, though.