# PostgreSQL Integer in Array is not merge-joinable

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, outer-join

I would like to perform a FULL OUTER JOIN ON a condition that is an integer being in an array of integer.

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT thing FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = ANY(t2.array_of_ids)
```

But I get the following error:

> FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions

Is there a way to make this condition merge-joinable ?

Comment: The piece of code I gave works with INNER JOIN. I would basically like to use it with an outer join.
In other words, I want every element from table1 and from table 2 to be in the selection. If an element from table1 has an ID in the column array_of_ids of table2, I want them to be the same row (I use aggregate function afterwards)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.I'd agree that saying that it works with inner join as you did would help. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". PS I expect this is a faq, have you googled with site:stackoverflow.com? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239060/3404097) help? (See documentation re ANY.) Maybe the array contains operator? Or convert the array to a table.

Comment: I see two options: 1) normalize your data model, so you don't need to join using an array. 2) use two queries: a left join, a right join and combine them with union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Does it work like this?

```
SELECT thing
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (table2 t2 CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t2.array_of_ids) t2_id
     )
     ON t1.id = t2_id;
```

The issue with this is that it will multiply the number of rows.  So, how about just constructing the `FULL JOIN`?

```
SELECT . . .
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (table2 t2 CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(t2.array_of_ids) t2_id
     )
     ON t1.id = t2_id
UNION ALL
SELECT . . .
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM UNNEST(t2.array_of_ids) t2_id JOIN
                       table1 t1
                  ON t2_id = t1.id
                 );
```